# Directly calling background task in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-store

I'm preparing for the new microsoft certification exam [Universal Windows Platform – App Data, Services, and Coding Patterns](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-355.aspx)

**Is it possible to directly call background task from Windows 10 (Universal WIndows) app?** As far as I know, only triggers like SystemTrigger or TimerTrigger can trigger the execution of background task

In the skill mesuread section from the link is:

> #### Implement background tasks
>
> Create a background task, register a background task, set and respond to triggers, debug a background task, implement a lock screen app, share data/events between an app and its background tasks; **directly calling a background task**

The last point, directly calling a background task, what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that would be the `ApplicationTrigger` class.

See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger.aspx

This is btw new in UWP. In A Windows (Phone) Store 8.1 app there was no way to trigger a background task directly from the app.

Comment: Do I have to do something special in the package manifest declarations, because when I call RequestAsync I receive UnknownError enumeration. and I clear the Run method just for testing.

Comment: Yes, you have to add "Background Tasks" under "Declarations" in the manifest in the app which uses the background task. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, right, I have to use Audio and systemEvent Tasks, but it does not allow to have more than one active, it is a weird behavior